# FIR filter format - Brutefir - Volumio

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response

I am trying to compensate for the high frequency droop of a TDA1543 based nos DAC. One straightforward method [is described here.](https://www.diyaudio.com/archive/blogs/abraxalito/869-using-audacity-do-nos-droop-correction.html)

Having played the resulting `.wav`, which I feel satisfied with, I am trying to replicate the results with `Brutefir`.

In essence it is a three tap filter:

> 1,
>   -0.15,
>   0.026

The setup I am using is: `Volumio` + `Brutefir` plugin.

What I have attempted is to simply save the three numbers as `.txt` file and load them into `Brutefir`.

For some reason I am doing something wrong because there is no resulting music.
Is `Brutefir` expecting an even number of taps? Is the format the problem?

Comment: what's a "nos DAC"? Also, I'm pretty sure very few (if any) here know "Volumio" and "Brutefir". I guess that's software. What does it do?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I answered my own question.
So tried the same filter adding zeros to a total of 32 taps.
Plays great now and spectrum is better in the highs.
So this is the filter:

```
1, -0.15, 0.026, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
(Total taps: 32)
```